# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{6s^2-2}{\left(s^2+1\right)^3}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I would like to determine the inverse Laplace transform of $$\frac{6s^2-2}{\left(s^2+1\right)^3}.$$

What's the easiest way to do this? (Easy in the sense that it follows easily from some Laplace transform formula or is less computationally heavy.)

The official solution uses multiplication by the $t^n$ rule, but this works because they knew what function works when you take its derivative. I'm not sure how to "guess" the correct function or how to solve this question.

I have a test tomorrow and this question has been bugging me all day. I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: As a first step, consider expanding into partial fractions. You could also check if your expression has an antiderivative and apply [this rule](https://planetmath.org/inverselaplacetransformofderivatives). If you know about convolution you can also use [the relevant property](https://planetmath.org/laplacetransformofconvolution)

Comment: Writing the numerator as $6(s^2+1)-8$ and expanding out is likely the best bet.

Comment: @user170231 how would you do it in partial fractions?

Comment: @Eddie What is the result? I have a way using convolution...

Comment: @DonAntonio when i use partial fractions, i get what I started with, it doesn't seem to break it up into anything. What's the easiest method with convolution? I want to avoid solving 3 integrals

Comment: @eddie Check my answer. It is a rather long way, too. I don't think partial fractions can be useful in this case...

Comment: @DonAntonio is convolution the easiest way for this? I'm not a fan of integrating, but if that's the way to do to it, then i guess I'll use convolution

Comment: @eddie Well, is the straightest way I could see, using tables of Laplace Transform...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$\frac{6s^2-2}{(s^2+1)^3}=\left[6\frac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}+\frac4{(s^2+1)^2}\right]\cdot\frac1{s^2+1}$$

and thus we have that

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{6s^2-2}{(s^2+1)^3}\right)=f(t)\implies F(s):=\mathscr L\{f(t)\}(s)=\left[6\frac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}+\frac4{(s^2+1)^2}\right]\cdot\frac1{s^2+1}$$

and we can see the rightmost expression as the product of the transform of two functions, making $\;f\;$ a convolution:

$$\mathscr L^{-1}\left(6\frac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}\right)=6t\cos t+\mathscr L^{-1}\left(\frac4{(s^2+1)^2}\right)=6t\cos t+\mathscr L^{-1}\left(2\frac{2\cdot1^3}{(s^2+1)^2}\right)=$$

$$=6t\cos t+2\sin t-2t\cos t=2\sin t +4t\cos t\,,\;\;\text{and of course}\;\;\mathscr L^{-1}\left(\frac1{s^2+1}\right)=\sin t$$

and we thus get that

$$f(t)=\sin t*\left(2\sin t+4t\cos t\right)=2\sin t*\sin t+4\sin t*t\cos t$$

and now:

$$2\sin t*\sin t=2\int_0^t\sin(t-y)\sin y\,dy=\int_0^t\left(\cos(t-2y)-\cos t\right) dy=$$

$$=\left.-\frac12\sin(t-2y)\right|_0^t-t\cos t=-\frac12\left(\sin(-t)-\sin t\right)+t\cos t=\sin t-t\cos t$$

whereas

$$4\sin t*t\cos t=4\int_0^t\sin(t-y) y\cos y\,dy=4\int_0^ty\,\frac12\left(\sin t+\sin(t-2y)\right)dy=$$

$$=\left.\left[t^2\sin t+\int_0^ty\sin (t-2y)dy\right]\stackrel{\text{by parts}}=t^2\sin t+y\cos(t-2y)\right|_0^t-\int_0^t\cos(t-2y)dy=$$

$$=t^2\sin t+t\cos t+\left.\frac12\sin(t-2y)\right|_0^t=t^2\sin t+t\cos t+\frac12\left(\sin(-t)-\sin t\right)=$$

$$=t^2\sin t+t\cos t-\sin t$$

and finally:

$$=f(t)=\sin t-t\cos t+t^2\sin t+t\cos t-\sin t=t^2\sin t$$

Comment: I believe there's a mistake in here somewhere. The inverse should be $t^2\sin(t)$

Comment: Indeed, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Laplace+transform+of+2t+Sin%28t%29

Comment: Yes, I know that's what Wolfram says...yet I can't see the mistake, and Wolfram has had quite some mistakes in the past so unles someone find some mistake in my answer I am taking it as the actual answer.

Comment: Darn! I just calculated by hand...very long and messy work...the Laplace Transform of $\;t^2\sin t\;$ ...and it is indeed $\;\frac{6s^2-2}{(s^2+1)^3}\;$ ...! So my work must have a mistake somewhere...Apparently not a big one since I got some thing close to the actual answer, but still. I shall look for it...and you all are warmly invited to do the same.

Comment: Found it! It was in the second line after "whereas": there was the integral $$\int_0^t y\sin t\,dy=\frac12t^2\sin t$$ which I "solved" just as $\;2t\sin t\;$ ...(and all times $\;\frac42=2\;$, of course). I edited my answer and that's it. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with almost no calculation: since partial fractions would include $\frac{1}{(s-i)^3}$, which is both $\mathscr{L}\frac12t^2e^{it}$ and $\frac{s^3-3s+i(3s^2-1)}{(s^2+1)^3}$, and since $6s^2-2=0(s^3-3s)+2(3s^2-1)$, the solution is $2\Im\frac12t^2e^{it}=t^2\sin t$.

Answer (score 1):

DonAntonio's answer covers the partial fraction/convolution approach. One could fully expand into partial fractions to get

$$F(s) = \frac6{(s^2+1)^2} - \frac8{(s^2+1)^3}$$

The inverse transform of the first term will involve convolving the inverse of $\frac1{s^2+1}$ with itself, and the second term can be evaluated by convolving that result with $\frac1{s^2+1}$. But that's rather cumbersome.

---

As another option, recall the inverse transform of the second derivative,

$$\mathscr L^{-1}_t\left\{F''(s)\right\} = t^2 f(t)$$

Integrating twice, we have

$$\int \left(\int \frac{6\sigma^2-2}{(\sigma^2+1)^3}\,d\sigma\right) \, ds = c_1 - \int \frac{2s}{(s^2+1)^2} \, ds = c_2 + c_1s + \frac1{1+s^2}$$

Now,

$$F(s) = c_2 + c_1 s + \frac1{1+s^2} \implies f(t) = c_2 \delta(t) + c_1\delta'(t) + \sin(t)$$

which effectively reduces to $f(t)=\sin(t)$ when $t>0$, and hence

$$\mathscr L^{-1}_t\left\{\frac{6s^2-2}{(s^2+1)^3}\right\} = t^2 f(t) = \boxed{t^2\sin(t)}$$